# using d3.js, how can i select a particular <g> which has particular text in <text> as its child?

Tags: d3.js

intial html is as follows.

```
<svg>
<g>
    <rect></rect>
    <text>selectThis</text>
</g>

<g>
    <rect></rect>
    <text>dont_selectThis</text>
</g>
```

i have to select the g tag which has the child text tag and its value "selectThis" and should append some other text tags to it, such that the final output will be

```
<svg>
<g>
    <rect></rect>
    <text>selectThis</text>
    <text> extra added </text>
</g>

<g>
    <rect></rect>
    <text>dont_selectThis</text>
</g>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by filtering an initial selection:

```
d3.selectAll("g")
  .filter(function() {
    return d3.select(this).select("text").text() == "selectThis";
  });
```